# Passing data from a delegate to a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsarray

I have a `ViewController`:

```
@interface SubmitCampaignViewController:UIViewController<SocialPagesViewControllerDelegate>
```

And a `SocialPagesViewController` with `UITableView` like this:

```
@protocol SocialPagesViewControllerDelegate;
@interface SocialPagesViewController : BaseViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SocialPagesViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *pages;   
@end
```

I would like to to pass data from `SubmitCampaignViewController` to `SocialPagesViewController`.

So I wrote like this:

```
SocialPagesViewController *socialViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"socialPages"];
socialViewController.delegate = self;
socialViewController.pages = objects;
[self presentViewController:socialViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

However, although objects is not 0, self.pages.count is 0.

**SocialPagesViewController.m**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    DLog(@"%d",self.pages.count);
    return self.pages.count;
}
```

How can I pass objects `NSArray` from `SubmitCampaignViewController` to `SocialPagesViewController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the referrence of array as strong.
 `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pages;`

Comment: This is the correct answer. But wouldn't it harm me if I am using strong and ARC? would it know to release the object when I dismiss the viewcontroller of social?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the setter of `pages` to `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *pages;` since you require the same array `object` into `pages`.

At the point of presenting socialViewController..

```
socialViewController.pages = [objects copy];
```

Comment: Is it better to use copy vs strong?

Comment: if you use strong, it copies the pointer value from original one.retain also increment the reference count by one. but in case of copy, it duplicate the data referenced by the pointer and assign it to copy's instance variable.Preferably copy is better, in your case.

Comment: So isn't it better to use strong in this case?

Comment: No major disadvantage using strong.'Copy' is used if you need the value of the object as it is at this moment, and you don't want that value to reflect any changes made by other owners of the object.